Ubuntu 24.04 kernel 6.8.0-4x incompatible with vmware 17.6
I have a new system with Intel i9 processor and 32GB of SRAM. OS: Ubuntu with kernel 6.8.0-45. The old system is broken.
enter image description hereFor wy work I need to use vmware workstation and with this OS I had to install the version 17.6.
I found that this version of vmware is incompatible with the kernel and as soon as the vm starts the system becomes corrupt: the network doesn't work, the terminal doesn't work, it is impossible to open any type of application. So I have to kill the system manually because it is also impossible to do the shutdown (after one night it is still waiting for the shutdown).
Here are the picture of the main error I see:
Error during work
During the shutdown I see the errors shown in the following pictures:shutdown error 1 shutdown error 2
If the vmware is not working everything works well.
I tried to downgrade the kernel to the 6.8.0-40 (someone says that it can work with vmware), but it seems that there are incompatibilities and at the boot the system goes in recovery mode
I saw that for the vmware version 17.5.1 someone found a patch, so I would like to know if that patch could work also for the 17.6 version.
In any case, anbody knows if there is a solution to be able to use Ubuntu 24.04 with vmware 17.6?
Thanks
Claudio

Hi I had the exact same problem this solved it ( found the solution on vmware forum)
Here's a step-by-step guide to resolve your issue with VMware Workstation 17.6.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 or 24.04 after updating to the Linux kernel 6.8.0:
Step 1: Reboot Your System
Before making changes, ensure your system is in a clean state. Reboot your machine.
Step 2: Extract the vmmon Module

Open a terminal.
Run the following command to extract the current vmmon module:
tar xvf /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar



Step 3: Download the Fixed Header File

Use curl to download the corrected pgtbl.h file:
curl -o vmmon-only/include/pgtbl.h https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/4c2a103fd2d71f2084f1fe7ceacb816b9832ffa2/vmmon-only/include/pgtbl.h



Step 4: Create a New tar File

Create a new tar file containing the modified module:
tar cvf vmmonnew.tar vmmon-only/



Step 5: Backup the Original vmmon Module

Create a backup of the original vmmon.tar file:
sudo cp /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmonold.tar



Step 6: Replace the Original Module

Copy the new tar file to replace the original vmmon.tar:
sudo cp vmmonnew.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar



Step 7: Rebuild the VMware Modules

Run the following command to rebuild all VMware modules:
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all



Step 8: Test VMware Workstation

Start VMware Workstation and check if your virtual machines are functioning properly with the new kernel.

Step 9: Reverting Changes (if necessary)
If you encounter issues and want to revert to the original vmmon module:

Copy the backup back to the original filename:
sudo cp /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmonold.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar


Run the rebuild command again:
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all



Note

Make sure you have the necessary development tools installed to compile kernel modules (like build-essential, linux-headers-$(uname -r), etc.). You can install them using:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)



By following these steps, you should be able to get VMware Workstation working with the latest patched Ubuntu kernels.

Thanks a lot @Mister-3. Are you sure that it is not necessary a change also in the vmnet module? The bug is involving also the network on my pc.

I did the change, but now vmware says: "Could not connect 'Ethernet0' to virtual network '/dev/vmnet0'.

I had the same issue what I did to resolve it was revert back to version 17.5.2 and Compile the VMware Workstation Pro Kernel Modules . Here is the link I used to do it:
https://thelinuxforum.com/articles/969-how-to-compile-the-vmware-workstation-pro-kernel-modules-on-ubuntu-debian
And it is stable with 17.5.2 .
I think its better to just use this version until they fix the issue with the 17.6

I tried this, but I get another error:
tmp/modconfig-jxSdbv/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c: In function ‘HostIF_LookupUserMPN’:
/tmp/modconfig-jxSdbv/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1179:11: error: implicit declaration of function ‘UserVa2MPN’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
1179 |    *mpn = UserVa2MPN((VA)uvAddr);
I'm running:

If it can help others VMWARE users, there are still error with last build WS-17.6.1-24319023 on default install of 24.04.1 with last kernel 6.8.0-48.
WMware is installed but without any network support.
VM can be run but without any network. ("can't fin /ethernet0" etc).
sudo apt install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
/tmp/modconfig-PVTGAS/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Add() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Remove()
/tmp/modconfig-PVTGAS/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Remove() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Test()
/tmp/modconfig-PVTGAS/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c: In function ‘HostIF_LookupUserMPN’:
/tmp/modconfig-PVTGAS/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1179:11: error: implicit declaration of function ‘UserVa2MPN’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 1179 |    *mpn = UserVa2MPN((VA)uvAddr);
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-PVTGAS/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: .text: unexpected end of section
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243 : /tmp/modconfig-PVTGAS/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o] Erreur 1
make[3]: *** Attente des tâches non terminées....
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-48-generic/Makefile:1925 : /tmp/modconfig-PVTGAS/vmmon-only] Erreur 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240 : __sub-make] Erreur 2
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-48-generic »

And Virtual internet module is still not loaded :
$ journalctl -xeu vmware.service
░░ 
░░ L'unité (unit) vmware.service a commencé à démarrer.
nov. 08 11:56:56 Precision5560 vmware[66952]: Starting VMware services:
nov. 08 11:56:56 Precision5560 vmware[66952]:    Virtual machine monitor - done
nov. 08 11:56:56 Precision5560 vmware[66952]:    Virtual machine communication interface - done
nov. 08 11:56:56 Precision5560 vmware[66952]:    VM communication interface socket family - done
nov. 08 11:56:56 Precision5560 vmware[66952]:    Virtual ethernet - failed
nov. 08 11:56:56 Precision5560 vmware[66952]:    VMware Authentication Daemon - done
nov. 08 11:56:56 Precision5560 systemd[1]: vmware.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Available for any question to help to make VMWARE working well on ubuntu.
